# Play not answering HTTP requests

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm currently exploring similar alternatives to Ruby on Rails, and have been considering Playframework using Scala (cuz I'm not fond of Java).

Problem is, even if the default sample of application works very fine, everytime I try doing actual work with Playframework, it end up with it not answering HTTP requests.

It compiles after the first request, but doesn't answer it.
Then it ignores every other request (not even re-compiling when I changed stuff).
It does kick out an user typing an incorrect request, but it never times you out if the request is correct.

What is this ?

I'm using Playframework 1.2.3 with the Scala module. Is there any way to get a better insight at what's happening ?

Answer (score 1):

So it never times out, isn't it? as if it was compiling forever?
If yes, maybe you have problems with the Scala compiler which is slower than Java compiler and requires more stack. Generally if you don't have enough stack, it should crash with a StackOverflow.
YOu can try to run play with "play run -Xss1024k" for example to increase the stack size.

If you get empty answer, it means the problem is somewhere else like routes or bad object returned from your controller.

Anyway, Play-Scala is still young and in evolution so it's not a reliable solution for an entreprise solution if you're not yet an expert in Scala and don't already know Play IMO. It's already robust and stable but not well documented and as complete as Java version.

Finally, you say you're not found of Java and it's something I can understand but you should really give a try to Play/Java since it's completely different from any other Java stuff. I can say that because I'm an old Java developer and find the language getting a bit outdated in its syntax and basic features. I don't really like Java EE web frameworks in general because they are not really productive and user-friendly. When I found Play more than one year ago, it was like a breath of air for me. You get the best of modern web frameworks and the best of the Java world which are all the robust and approved entreprise tools coming from opensource. I've never been deceived by it since this time.